# Trouble centering align*

Tags: align

I am having problems center text that has been aligned. For some reason the second align is not centered. Here is an image of the output.[image: Output]

Below is my code...

```
words
\begin{align*}
    1&=ak_1+bl_1\\
    n&=n(ak_1+bl_1)\\
    &=nak_1+nbl_1\\
    &=ak_n+bl_n\\
\end{align*}
words
\begin{align*}
    n&=ak_n+bl_n\\
    &=ak_n+abx+bl_n-abx\\
    &=a(k_n+bx)+b(l_n-ax)\\
    &=ar+bs&\\
\end{align*}
more words
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.For star try to omit last `\\` in your equations. They introduce additional vertical space shich seems to be your problem..

Comment: Welcome! You have a trailing ``&\\`` in the second alignment: remove it.

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: What's the second `&` in the final line of the second `align*` environment supposed to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You have an improper `&` in the last line of the second alignment, which sets up a second set of alignments; those columns are empty, but the space between the first and the second set is accounted for.

You also have trailing `\\` that should be removed.

### Original

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{showframe} % just for the example

\begin{document}

words
\begin{align*}
    1&=ak_1+bl_1\\
    n&=n(ak_1+bl_1)\\
    &=nak_1+nbl_1\\
    &=ak_n+bl_n\\
\end{align*}
words
\begin{align*}
    n&=ak_n+bl_n\\
    &=ak_n+abx+bl_n-abx\\
    &=a(k_n+bx)+b(l_n-ax)\\
    &=ar+bs&\\
\end{align*}
more words

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Fixed version

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{showframe} % just for the example

\begin{document}

words
\begin{align*}
    1&=ak_1+bl_1\\
    n&=n(ak_1+bl_1)\\
    &=nak_1+nbl_1\\
    &=ak_n+bl_n
\end{align*}
words
\begin{align*}
    n&=ak_n+bl_n\\
    &=ak_n+abx+bl_n-abx\\
    &=a(k_n+bx)+b(l_n-ax)\\
    &=ar+bs
\end{align*}
more words

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Note

The frame is just for demonstration purposes. Don't load the `showframe` package yourself.

Answer (score 1):

A mentioned in my comment, the last line in your aligned equations have surplus `\\`- Also in secon groupu of equations is one ampersund to much ... Try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}

    \begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{align*}
1   & = ak_1+bl_1           \\
n   & = n(ak_1+bl_1)        \\
    & = nak_1+nbl_1         \\
    & = ak_n+bl_n
\end{align*}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{align*}
n   & = ak_n+bl_n           \\
    & = ak_n+abx+bl_n-abx   \\
    & = a(k_n+bx)+b(l_n-ax) \\
    & = ar+bs
\end{align*}
\lipsum[2]
    \end{document}
```

[image]